# accumulatedweight throws cv:Exception error

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am new to OpenCV and trying to find contours and draw rectangle on them, here's my code but its throwing cv::Exception when it comes to accumulatedweighted().
i tried to make both src(Original Image) and dst(background) by converting to CV_32FC3 and then finding avg using accumulatedweighted.

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

static void help()
{
cout << "\nThis is a Example to implement CAMSHIFT to detect multiple motion objects.\n";
}

Rect rect;
VideoCapture capture;
Mat currentFrame, currentFrame_grey, differenceImg, oldFrame_grey,background;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

bool first = true;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
//Create a new movie capture object.
capture.open(0);

if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    //error in opening the video input
    cerr << "Unable to open video file: " /*<< videoFilename*/ << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}   

//capture current frame from webcam
capture >> currentFrame;

//Size of the image.
CvSize imgSize;
imgSize.width = currentFrame.size().width; //img.size().width
imgSize.height = currentFrame.size().height; ////img.size().height

//Images to use in the program.
currentFrame_grey.create( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U);//image.create().  

while(1)
{
    capture >> currentFrame;//VideoCapture& VideoCapture::operator>>(Mat& image)                

    //Convert the image to grayscale.
    cvtColor(currentFrame,currentFrame_grey,CV_RGB2GRAY);//cvtColor()

    currentFrame.convertTo(currentFrame,CV_32FC3);
    background = Mat::zeros(currentFrame.size(), CV_32FC3);
    accumulateWeighted(currentFrame,background,1.0,NULL);

    imshow("Background",background);

    if(first) //Capturing Background for the first time
    {
        differenceImg = currentFrame_grey.clone();//img1 = img.clone()
        oldFrame_grey = currentFrame_grey.clone();//img2 = img.clone()
        convertScaleAbs(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);//convertscaleabs()
        first = false;
        continue;
    }

    //Minus the current frame from the moving average.
    absdiff(oldFrame_grey,currentFrame_grey,differenceImg);//absDiff()

    //bluring the differnece image
    blur(differenceImg, differenceImg, imgSize);//blur()

    //apply threshold to discard small unwanted movements
    threshold(differenceImg, differenceImg, 25, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);//threshold()

    //find contours
    findContours(differenceImg,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0)); //findcontours()

    //draw bounding box around each contour
    //for(; contours! = 0; contours = contours->h_next)
    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        rect = boundingRect(contours[i]); //extract bounding box for current contour
        //drawing rectangle
        rectangle(currentFrame, cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y), cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);                 
    }       

    //New Background
    convertScaleAbs(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);

    //display colour image with bounding box
    imshow("Output Image", currentFrame);//imshow()

    //display threshold image
    imshow("Difference image", differenceImg);//imshow()

    //clear memory and contours
    //cvClearMemStorage( storage );
    //contours = 0;
    contours.clear();

    //background = currentFrame;

    //press Esc to exit
    char c = cvWaitKey(33);
    if( c == 27 ) break;

}

// Destroy All Windows.
destroyAllWindows();

return 0;
}
```

Please Help to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to [RTFM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted) before asking here.

so, you missed the alpha param as well as the dst Mat in your call to addWeighted

```
Mat dst; 
accumulateWeighted(currentFrame, 0.5 background, 0.5, 0, dst);
```

also, no idea, what the whole thing should achieve. adding up the current frame before diffing it does not make any sense to me.

if you planned to do background separation, throw it all away, and use one of the builtin [backgroundsubtractors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractor) instead

Comment: Thanks @berak, BackgroundSubtractor worked to subtract background, in the example i have posted, i was trying to implement CAMSHIFT to detect multiple objects, As mentioned in this [Paper](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iosrjournals.org%2Fccount%2Fclick.php%3Fid%3D1959&ei=lv6OU-PlDoO0uATdyYDoBw&usg=AFQjCNHhpcKgRTYLdhbL-wQJG7lq4YTIgg&bvm=bv.68235269,d.c2E&cad=rja).